# Passing function arguments to add_action within a class

Tags: wordpress

As in codex the `add_action`, accept passing function parameters

```
add_action( $hook, $function_to_add, $priority, $accepted_args );
```

when i pass add_action in construct function return error and say `messing argument 2 in function YPE_bsn_gfont`.

Also when I pass function parameters in `add_action` like this `add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this,'YPE_bsn_gfont'), 10, 2);` also return same error.

How I can pass `YPE_bsn_gfont` method into `add_action` without occurs any error

```
<?php
class YPE_Bsn_Gfonts {
public function __construct() {
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this,'YPE_bsn_gfont'));
}
public function YPE_bsn_gfont($bsn_option, $id) {
    $YPE_gfont = get_option($bsn_option_group);
    $font_name = str_replace(' ', '+', $YPE_gfont[$id]);
    $font_id   = str_replace(' ', '-', $YPE_gfont[$id].'-google-font');
    $fonts_url = esc_url(add_query_arg(array('family' => $font_name, 'subset' => urlencode('latin,latin-ext')), 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css'));
    wp_enqueue_style($font_id, $fonts_url, array(), null);
}
public function YPE_bsn_use_fonts() {
    $this->YPE_bsn_gfont('YPE_layout_name', 'logo-fontfamily');
}
}
$YPE_GFONTS = new YPE_Bsn_Gfonts();
?>
```